# Is NULL a valid FILE*?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, null-pointer

I would like to have a function along the lines of

```
/*In header*/
void foo(FILE *outpt=stdout);

/*In implementation*/
void foo(FILE *outpt)
{
    if(outpt) fprintf(outpt, "Hello!");
}
```

But this code is (obviously) broken if `NULL==stdout`.  (**Edit:** Jonathan Leffler points out that this code is already broken, because C has no default arguments.  My C++ is showing, but the idea remains.)

C specifies that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are implementation-defined `FILE*` constants, but I can't find a reference indicating that these constants are not `NULL`.  Moreover, I can't find anything suggesting that `NULL` might not be a valid open file!

In MSVS, `fprintf(NULL, "Hello!")` calls `abort()`, suggesting that `NULL` is indeed an invalid `FILE*` specification.

C++ seems to follow C in this regard.  I'm ultimately a C++ programmer, but I'll take a C answer, because it then likely carries over to C++ for backwards compatibility.  So: **does a C or C++ specification (including C2x and C++20) guarantee that `NULL` is an invalid `FILE*` specification?**

Comment: C does not support default arguments — the declaration of `foo()` is erroneous in C.

Comment: In C11 [§7.1.4 Use of library functions ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4p1) it says: _Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, …), …, the behavior is undefined._. The specification of `fprintf()` does not say that NULL is a valid file pointer; using NULL is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Also, in C11 [§7.24.1 Introduction](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1) (to `<stdio.h>`), it says: _`stderr`, `stdin`, `stdout` … are expressions of type ''pointer to FILE'' that point to the FILE objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams._. Nothing about being constants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 [7.21.1/3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p3) describes the standard file handles thusly:

> The macros are […]
>
> `stderr`
> `stdin`
> `stdout`
>
> which are expressions of type "pointer to `FILE`" that point to the `FILE` objects associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.

They would not point to any such objects if their values were null.

Comment: It also doesn't say that they have to be constants. In the GNU C library, they are not constants, so you can't write at file scope `static FILE *fp = stdout;` because `stdout` is not a constant expression.

Comment: You may copy my other [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084675/is-null-a-valid-file#comment113323064_64084675) into your answer if you wish, with or without credit. (And the previous one under your answer too.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sure, although they are implied to be constant in that there is only one such object for each standard stream.

Comment: No; they're uniquely valued non-constants.  If they were constants, they'd be usable in file scope initializers.  Once upon a long time ago, you could write `static FILE *fp = stdout;` and it worked because `#define stdout (&__iob[1])` was used, and `__iob` was an array of `FILE` structures, so the address was indeed a constant.  That was _not_ guaranteed by the standard, so when the GNU C library changed (early 2000s, IIRC), it broke working code from other systems.

Comment: I made changes in code on 1999-06-02 because of the GNU C Library change — so that change will have been made in early 1999, probably, or possibly 1998.  My check-in comment identified the Linux version as "(RedHat 6.0; kernel 2.2.5, glibc 2.1.1)".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I understand: I was deliberately referring to a normal-English meaning of “constant” (*i.e.*, not changing over time).

Comment: That's not a safe interpretation of `constant` in the context of C (or C++) programming.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Sorry!  I tried to specify (“in that”).  I use “constant *expression*” for the technical sense, but that may be a C++-ism.

Answer (score 1):

NULL is not a valid FILE*! Since stdout and stdin are treated like any other stream, the following applies…

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html

> RETURN VALUE
> Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a
> FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to
> indicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

A NULL pointer, by definition, does not point to a valid object of *any* type.  Whether or not the pointer type is `FILE *` doesn't matter.

Section 6.3.2.3p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says the following regarding NULL pointers:

> An  integer  constant  expression  with  the  value  0,  or  such  an
> expression  cast  to  type `void *`, is called a *null pointer
> constant*. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type,
> **the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to
> compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.**

Attempting to dereference a NULL pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Section 6.5.3.3p4 of the C standard regarding the indirection operator states:

> The unary `*` operator denotes indirection.  If the operand points to
> a function, the result is a  function  designator;  if  it  points  to
> an  object,  the  result  is  an  lvalue  designating  the object.
> If  the  operand  has  type  ‘‘pointer  totype’’,  the  result  has
> type  ‘‘type’’.   **If  an invalid  value  has  been  assigned  to  the
> pointer,  the  behavior  of  the  unary `*`operator  is undefined.
> <sup>102)</sup>**

And footnote 102 states:

> ... Among  the  invalid  values  for  dereferencing  a  pointer  by
> the  unary `*` operator  are  **a  null  pointer**, an address
> inappropriately aligned for the type of object pointed to, and the
> address of an object after the end of its lifetime.

As these apply to NULL pointers in general, by extension it means that a `FILE *` being set to NULL does not point to a valid `FILE` object.